# Generate ".env" when Deploying with Bitbucket AWS CodeDeploy add-on

Tags: bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

How to generate ".env" when Deploying with Bitbucket AWS CodeDeploy add-on?

I see `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` can generate .env from bitbucket environment variables, but, how tie it up with Bitbucket AWS CodeDeploy add-on?

`appspec.yml` - can trigger script on deployment but how can I make it get .env from bitbucket environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitBucket` should not create `.env`, this service should know nothing about production `.env`. Instead the production `.env` should sit on secure `AWS S3 bucket` where only `AWS CodeDeploy` scripts can take it and put on the instance.

it would be copied like this

```
sudo aws --region us-east-2 s3 cp "s3://${S3_NAME}/prod.env" "${EC2_DIRECTORY}/.env"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html), BitBucket should make the environments available in the build environment, and you should be able to access them directly in your scripts run by your `appspec.yml` just like you would access any other environment variables.

For example, if we had an appspec like this:

```
hooks:
   AfterInstall:
     - location: scripts/runTests.sh
       timeout: 180
```

You could access the environment variables in `scripts/runTests.sh` like this:

```
# scripts/runTests.sh
echo "$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER"
# Or, use in some other valid way in your script
```

Comment: I have not validated myself. I saw no one else responded to this question, so I did a little research and tried to offer a solution. If you try it and it doesn't work, I'll remove the answer.

Comment: I tried it did not work for me. Sorry. It may work for bitbucket pipelines, but it does not work for AWS CodeDeploy.